# update duplicate issue in laravel-5.5 in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I use this function to insert data form form:

controller:

```
public function store(request $request)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
         'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
         'mobile' => 'nullable|unique:users',
       ]);
       User::create($request->all());
       return redirect(route('users'));
}
```

for update I use this:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
       $this->validate($request, [
         'email' => 'required|unique:users|email',
         'mobile' => 'nullable|unique:users',
       ]);
       $user->update($request->all());
       return redirect(route('users'));
}
```

I have a problem. I can not save (update) edited form.

because it return an error:

> 1062 Duplicate entry for email and mobile

In edited form,maybe I wouldn't change email...so I want save form without change current email...

How can I manage it?

Comment: In your update function, can you return $request; before the update function, let's see what you request is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the record for which you're comparing:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,'.$user->id.'|email',
'mobile' => 'nullable|unique:users,mobile,'.$user->id
```